# Camera Calibration fails to run on ROS

Tags: ros, cameras, calibration

I am running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I am doing a mono-camera calibration and trying to follow the [camera calibration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) on the ROS Wiki.

I give the following command:

> rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square
>   0.108 image:=/my_camera/image camera:=/my_camera

I get the following error:

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File
>   "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 47,
>   in  import cv2 ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to
>   import

I thought it was to do with updating `numpy` and did a `rosdep` update but no difference.

What is a possible way to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**
I uninstalled and reinstalled ROS completely from scratch. I still get the same error. Should I have to look somewhere outside ROS?

Answer (score 1):

Install OpenCV-Python, it will solve the `import cv2` error.

You can refer the following link for installation, [Install OpenCV-Python in Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing stereo or mono camera calibration?  Can you post more code? (Please update the question, don't post code in a comment on this answer)

I ask because there's a few things to check. Highlights from the tutorial:

> Start by getting the dependencies and compiling the driver.

```
$ rosdep install camera_calibration

$ rosmake camera_calibration
```

> Make sure that your monocular camera is publishing images over ROS. List the topics to check that the images are published:

```
$ rostopic list
```

> This will show you all the topics published, check to see that there is an image_raw topic. The default topics provided by most ROS camera drivers are:
>   /camera/camera_info
>   /camera/image_raw
>   If you have multiple cameras or are running the driver in its own namespace, *your topic names may differ*.

Comment: Hi. So I am doing a mono-camera calibration. There is no more code to post since I am using the default ROS node. You are right about the topic names  since uvc_camera pulishes in the topic /image_raw but that will not solve the error and does not as I checked it. Regarding repos, they are up to date.

Comment: @Nagsaver - What is the namespace of the camera you are using? Does it match the definition you are using? (camera:=\my_camera) What do you get when you list topics? Do you get any errors when you install/make camera_calibration?

Comment: I get /image_raw and /camera_info as the topics when I do rostopic list. I tried with the new topic names and it gives the same error as expected because the error is related to numpy. Regarding the camera_calibration package,it builds successfully without any errors when I do rosmake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating numpy directly? rosdep does not care about pip packages.

```
sudo pip install numpy -U
```